# Calling a JSON text file from a server with diacritics using getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
I have a text file on a server with JSON data   

[ {
    "Organization":"Stony Brook",
    "First":"Gábor",
    "MI":"",
    "Last":"Balázsi",
    "Suffix":"",
    "email":"gabor.balazsi@stonybrook.edu",
    "Affiliations":"Stony Brook",
    "PMID_Include":"9117534,28489916,26324468",
    "PMID_Exclude":"7111147,27010473",
    "PMID_Pending":"26764736, 28165024, 27111147, 11690057, 12888502, 15870424, 17301801, 17652177, 18985025, 20174676, 21119761, 21468986, 22343619, 22745748, 24792166, ",
    "Date_Ran":""
}]
```

When I call it back with

```
$.getJSON("http://website.com/app/json_files/" + file_name, function (data) {
```

The diacritics come in garbled. The accented a's are not presented.  Is there anything that I can do to fix this and preserve the accents?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you are calling getJSON, your file should be ideally a .json file, try renaming it

Second,

It is required that your data is saved as UTF-8. I suspect that your file is not UTF-8 encoded. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: file extension is irrelevant so long as it contains valid json

Comment: Thanks but file name is .json-- and has been checked for formatting with various online sources. The file_name is just a variable so I can identify different files. I even added    $.ajaxSetup({
                    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                });

Answer (score 0):

OK- it was my own stupidity.  I had ran my file through notepad and had saved it as ANSI without knowing it.  I changed the encoding type to UTF-8 and saved the file again and it works fine.  Thanks for the input.